# Remove comma from last item of array using while

Tags: php

I know there are a lot of solutions for this issue but none seem to match how I am doing it. Maybe using For Each instead of While is better. Here is my code:

```
if ($cjobs > 1) {
    $query4 = "SELECT job FROM Job WHERE (Top_Lvl_Job = '" . $job . "') AND (Job <> '" . $job . "')";
    $results4 = sqlsrv_query($connPpp, $query4);
    $subtext .= " - Componants: ";
    While ($row4 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($results4)) {
        $comp = $row4['job'];
        $subtext .= $comp . ', ';}
}
```

How do I get rid of that last comma.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rtrim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the end of a string.

Use this after the `if` block.

```
$subtext  = rtrim($subtext , ',');
```

See [the doc](http://php.net/rtrim).

Comment: I have tried this but it seems to fail. Maybe I am sticking it in the wrong spot on the code.

Comment: @user1548989 You might want to show what you tried.

Comment: @user1548989 try it after the if block. Then it should work.

Comment: After the block worked. I am a dummy sometimes. Thanks for the help

Comment: @user1548989 accept this answer if it helps

Answer (score 0):

1. Using [rtrim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php#refsect1-function.rtrim-examplesrtrim) function.

   ```
   rtrim($subtext, ', ');
   ```
2. Using [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function.

   ```
   $subtext = substr($subtext,0,strlen($subtext)-2);
   ```

Comment: I have tried this but it seems to fail. Maybe I am sticking it in the wrong spot on the code.

Comment: Try echo $subtext outside the loop and let me know what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Add this after the While:

```
$subtext = rtrim ($subtext ", ");
```